# How to show error if ajax response is not returned after specfic time

Tags: jquery, ajax, response

How can i make sure that Ajax response was not sent because of some error? as the loader keeps loading,how can i make sure to display some message after specific time to user that something went wrong ? This is what i am trying.

```
  jQuery.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url:url,
        data:{id:id},

        beforeSend:function() {
            //loader()
        },
        success: function(msg) {

           // sucess
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:url,
        data:{id:id,type:type},
        timeout:5000 //This will set timeout to 5 seconds
        beforeSend:function() {
             // loader
        },
        success: function(msg) {

          // Success

        },
        error: function(){
           // It will fire once timeout is reached
           // If you have any other error in the code
           // like wrong function name etc,keep it mind timeout 
           // function wouldn't work,and you will see the error without 
           // waiting for the timeout function.

        })};
```

By the way you can get list of all the error as mentioned by @alok.

Answer (score 3):

```js
jQuery.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url:url,
        data:{id:id},

        beforeSend:function() {
            //loader()
        },
        success: function(msg) {

           // sucess
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            var msg = '';
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                msg = 'Time out error.';
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
            } else {
                msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
            }
        },
        timeout: 5000 // sets timeout to 3 seconds
    });
```

Comment: This is not working for me,as loader keeps loading @Alok

Comment: Can you upload the screenshot of your browser console

Comment: There is no error in the console.i got it as there was some issue with the code not with the ajax

Comment: @AsimShahzad just call the loader hide() in error: function(){}

Answer (score 1):

You can set time out option handle error in the error callback.

```js
$.ajax({
url: "test.html",
error: function(){
    // will fire when timeout is reached
},
success: function(){
    //do something
},
timeout: 3000 // sets timeout to 3 seconds
});
```

Comment: timeout function not working by this way,error gets load straight away without waiting for timeout function which is 20 seconds

Comment: By this way you are mentioning that 20 seconds is maximum, not minimum. You want the call to wait for specific seconds before failing or what is it do you expect?

Comment: Okay,if response is not returned after 20 seconds,then i need to show the error message

Comment: and Not before 20 seconds?

Comment: If the response is showing before 20 seconds, then that's because your script has returned an error (or improperly parsed JSON if expecting a JSON object) and it didn't need to get  to the timeout.